# inserting a 0 in blank textbox in reportviewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I have a report viewer which retrieves data from stored procedure to display. The boxes are to display a number. I was wondering is there a way in the reportviewer whether by an expression for the textbox to control that if the return from the stored procedure is nothing - or blank - to enter 0 instead of being empty? this report viewer is in a asp.net mvc c# project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a Replace under Common Functions that i used and worked fine:

```
=Replace(Fields!NumberTotals.Value,"NaN","0")
```